# Is that posssible to post method use in 2 server side url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I added a form and from this value all I set in const then post in API express js server with MongoDB how can I post method use post in 2url

```js
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = event.target.name.value
    const price = event.target.price.value
    const quantity = event.target.quantity.value
    const supplier = event.target.supplier.value
    const description = event.target.description.value
    const img = event.target.img.value

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/computer/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        price: price,
        quantity: quantity,
        supplier: supplier,
        description: description,
        img: img,
        email: user.email
      }),
      headers: {
        // 'authorization': `${user.email} ${localStorage.getItem("accssToken")}`,
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json));

  }
```